# "TFlite" to Caffe model

Tags: c++, tensorflow, opencv, caffe

I'm trying to use Opencv "cv::Net" with a Caffe model (.caffemodel and .prototxt) but the the model I have is a ".tflite".

Is it possible to convert ".tflite" to a caffer model so I can use it in opencv c++?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCV have open issue for this to be native https://github.com/opencv/opencv/wiki/OE-35.-TFLite-support.
Also in you can convert TFLite models to frozen TensorFlow graphs

```
bazel run --config=opt //tensorflow/lite/toco:toco -- --input_file=model.tflite --output_file=graph.pb --input_format=TFLITE --output_format=TENSORFLOW_GRAPHDEF
```

Answer (score 0):

TFLite models import is in progress: https://github.com/opencv/opencv/pull/23161